# Get network status when app starts

Tags: android

I want to learn network status when app starts,I am using this code

```
public class ConnectionChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
  @Override
  public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
  {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService( Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
    NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    NetworkInfo mobNetInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(     ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE );
    Log.w("Network Status:",""+activeNetInfo);
    if ( activeNetInfo != null )
    {

      Toast.makeText( context, "Active Network Type : " + activeNetInfo.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
    if( mobNetInfo != null )
    {
      Toast.makeText( context, "Mobile Network Type : " + mobNetInfo.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
  }
}
```

But this calling only when network status changed.I need to know network status when app is started.How can I do this ?

Comment: you mean that either net connected or not only ? or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small code example :

```
public boolean isOnline()
{
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And do not forget to set permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```